# Plotly Histogram xbins size using datetime

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, timedelta, bin

So I need to define the bin size, start and end for a histogram in Plotly.

The code would be like

```
go.Histogram(x=data, histnorm='',autobinx=False,
        xbins=dict(start=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 30),
                   end=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30),
                   size=(datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30)-datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 30))/30)
```

However, it is wrong, and the error would be:

```
TypeError: Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable
```

Does anyone know how to set bins in datetime fashion?

Answer (score 2):

For histograms, if the custom bins use time series, the specification is a string in time series format and the interval values are in D3 format. In the example below, M is the number of months and 2 is the number of months. For days, 'D' and the number of days. My code uses the data in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#custom-binning) to specify the month.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Histogram(x=df['date'],
                             y=df['GOOG'],
                             #histnorm='',
                             histfunc='count',
                             autobinx=False,
                             xbins=dict(
                                 start='2018-01-01',
                                 end='2019-12-30',
                                 size='M2'
                             )
                            )
               )
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.2)
fig.show()
```

[image]